# Regular expression issues in .net 6 value converter

Tags: c#, regex, .net-6.0, ivalueconverter

I am trying to learn some .net6 and c# and I am struggling with regular expressions a lot. More specificaly with Avalonia in Windows if that is relevant.
I am trying to do a small app with 2 textboxes. I write text on one and get the text "filtered" in the other one using a value converter.
I would like to filter math expressions to try to solve them later on. Something simple, kind of a way of writing text math and getting results real time.
I have been trying for several weeks to figure this regular expression on my own with no success whatsoever.
I would like to replace in my string "_Expression{BLABLA}" for "BLABLA". For testing my expressions I have been checking in http://regexstorm.net/ and https://regex101.com/ and according to them my matches should be correct (unless I misunderstood the results). But the results in my little app are extremely odd ***to me*** and I finally decided to ask for help.
Here is my code:

```
        private static string? FilterStr(object value)
        {
            if (value is string str)
            {
                string pattern = @"\b_Expression{(.+?)\w*}";
                Regex rgx = new(pattern);
                foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(str))
                {
                    string aux = "";
                    aux = match.Value;
                    aux = Regex.Replace(aux, @"_Expression{", "");
                    aux = Regex.Replace(aux, @"[\}]", "");
                    str = Regex.Replace(str, match.Value, aux);
                }
                return new string(str);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Then the results for some sample inputs are:
Input:

```
Some text
_Expression{x}
_Expression{1}
_Expression{4}
_Expression{4.5} _Expression{4+4}
_Expression{4-4} _Expression{4*x}
_Expression{x/x}
_Expression{x^4}
_Expression{sin(x)}
```

Output:

```
Some text
x
1{1}
1{4}
1{4.5} 1{4+4}
1{4-4} 1{4*x}
1{x/x}
1{x^4}
1{sin(x)}
```

or
Input:

```
Some text
_Expression{x}

_Expression{4}
_Expression{4.5} _Expression{4+4}
_Expression{4-4} _Expression{4*x}
_Expression{x/x}
_Expression{x^4}
_Expression{sin(x)}
```

Output:

```
Some text
x

_Expression{4}
4.5 _Expression{4+4}
4-4 _Expression{4*x}
x/x
_Expression{x^4}
_Expression{sin(x)}
```

It feels very confusing to me this behaviour. I can't see why "(.+?)" does not work with some of them and it does with others... Or maybe I haven't defined something properly or my Replace is wrong? I can't see it...

Thanks a lot for the time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some missing parts in your regular expression, for example it doesn't have the curly braces `{` and `}` escaped, since curly braces have a special meaning in a regular expression; they are used as [quantifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions#regular-expression-quantifiers).

Use the one below.
For extracting the math expression between the curly braces, it uses a [named capturing group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named-matched-subexpressions) with name `mathExpression`.

```
 _Expression\{(?<mathExpression>.+?)\}
```

- `_Expression\{` : start with the fixed text`_Expression{`
- `(?<mathExpression>` : start a named capturing group with name `mathExpression`
- `.+?` : take the next characters in a non greedy way
- `)` : end the named capturing group
- `\}` : end with the fixed character `}`

---

The below example will output 2 matches

```
Regex regex = new(@"_Expression\{(?<mathExpression>.+?)\}");
var matches = regex.Matches(@"_Expression{4.5} _Expression{4+4}");
foreach (Match match in matches.Where(o => o.Success))
{
    var mathExpression = match.Groups["mathExpression"];
    Console.WriteLine(mathExpression);
}
```

Output

```
4.5
4+4
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks for the solution and the detailed explanation pfx, I can't be grateful enough!